# How to prevent vTaskSuspend to interrupt critical section?

Tags: mutex, freertos

I have two tasks that share a resource. To make sure that both tasks do not use the resource at the same time, I use a mutex.
My problem is, that it can happen, that when I suspend one task, the mutex is not released and therefore the second task is locked.

How can I prevent FreeRTOS to suspend a task while it is in the critical section?

This way, I am able to reproduce the issue:

```
SemaphoreHandle_t mutex;

void task_1() {
    while (true) {
        if (xSemaphoreTake(mutex, 0) == pdTRUE) {
            do_critical_work_1();
            xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
        }
        vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

void task_2() {
    while (true) {
        if (xSemaphoreTake(mutex, 0) == pdTRUE) {
            do_critical_work_2();
            xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
        }
        vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}


int main() {
    TaskHandle_t task_handle_1 = NULL;
    xTaskCreate(task_1, "task_1", 512, NULL, 42, &task_handle_1);
    vTaskSuspend(task_handle_1);

    TaskHandle_t task_handle_2 = NULL;
    xTaskCreate(task_2, "task_2", 512, NULL, 42, &task_handle_2);  // stuck because task_handle_1 never relases the mutex
}
```

Comment: Just don’t suspend a task. Especially don’t do this asynchronously from another task. Note that suspend/resume a task is rarely used (for special purposes).

Comment: So, rather than suspending task_1, should I check a flag if I really need to collect data? I am suspending my tasks because I want to save battery and do not need to collect new values all the time, only when I enter a specific mode.

Comment: It’s a misunderstanding that suspending a task saves any energy. If that is your main goal you should investigate how to make use of your MCUs low power modes if available and/or ‘tickless idle’ support of FreeRTOS. Also you could rework your application to query some sensors (?) on a dedicated event i.e. make your tasks event driven state machines. That’s a much better approach anyway.